# Java BufferedReader is not working for custom size in android

Tags: java, android, bufferedreader

I am using BufferedReader for reading a log file which size is nearly 300-500kb.

The constructor below for BufferedReader with custom size.

```
/**
 * Creates a buffering character-input stream that uses an input buffer of
 * the specified size.
 *
 * @param  in   A Reader
 * @param  sz   Input-buffer size
 *
 * @exception  IllegalArgumentException  If {@code sz <= 0}
 */

public BufferedReader(Reader in, int sz) {
    super(in);
    if (sz <= 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Buffer size <= 0");
    this.in = in;
    cb = new char[sz];
    nextChar = nChars = 0;
}
```

And my codebase is here:

```
try {
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new 
    FileReader(file), 1000);

    String line;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        logBuilder.append(line);
    }
    bufferedReader.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I have tried with increasing and decreasing the size than the default size. Nothing is working for me. Each time its taking 4041 character by default.

What's i am doing wrong here? Why custom size is not working?